# Javascript Objects - Passed by Value or reference?

Tags: javascript, object

I am totally confused about object being passed by reference. 
In one book I read about "***primitive data types are passed by value and obj are passed by ref.***" 
another one says "***in ecmascript everything is passed by value***" 
in another one it's "***objects are not passed by value***" 
Why is't there a standard thing to consider. I tried it on dev console and results are even more confusing.

Any help or reference ?

Comment: And [Does JavaScript pass by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)

Comment: Objects are passed by reference. Other types such as string, number etc are passed by value. If you have any specific code in which you have confusion, please share.

Comment: Everything is quite "natural": strings and numbers are passed by value, objects are passed by reference...

Comment: @Avinash your reply is not accurate. try passing an object to a function and then replacing the object. You will be confused. Go through the above linked answers

Comment: It's always pass by value, but some values are references. ;-)

Comment: @Avinash: There are references in JS (they're called objects), but there is no pass-by-reference.

Comment: Yes. Correct. Thanks for rectifying. I had the concept correctly in my mind but couldn't convey it in correct words.